# pandas: conditional count across row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has months for columns, and various departments for rows.

```
                2013April  2013May  2013June
        Dep1        0         10        15
        Dep2        10        15        20
```

I'm looking to add a column that counts the number of months that have a value greater than 0. Ex:

```
                2013April  2013May  2013June  Count>0 
        Dep1        0         10        15       2
        Dep2        10        15        20       3
```

The number of columns this function needs to span is variable. I think defining a function then using .apply is the solution, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

first, pick your columns, `cols`

```
df[cols].apply(lambda s: (s > 0).sum(), axis=1)
```

this takes advantage of the fact that `True` and `False` are `1` and `0` respectively in python.

### actually, there's a better way:

```
(df[cols] > 0).sum(1)
```

because this takes advantage of numpy vectorization

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda s: (s > 0).sum(), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop

%timeit (df > 0).sum(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 319 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I did differently was selecting the columns through integers. Else, I'd have to type like 60 names.  `df[df.columns[0:16]]`

Comment: to select columns by position, use ``df.iloc[0:16]``

Comment: @Jeff, don't you mean *rows*? or did you mean `df.columns[0:16]`?

Comment: sorry, typo ``df.iloc[:,0:16]``, gets you the first 16 columns